# JQuery - show/hide isn't working

Tags: jquery, html, show-hide, toggleclass

So I've done a show/hide script that open and closes the element that's being clicked.
But now I can't get it to work somehow and i can't figger out why.

Can someone try take a look at it?

### HTML

```
<div id="fleresvar" class="fleresvar">  <u><b>Klik her for at se flere svar</b></u>

    <div id="txtmore" class="txtmore" style="display:none;">
        <div id="txtask1" style="text-decoration:underline;color:#8F8F8F;cursor:pointer;"></div>
        <div id="txtask2" style="text-decoration:underline;color:#8F8F8F;cursor:pointer;"></div>
        <div id="txtask3" style="text-decoration:underline;color:#8F8F8F;cursor:pointer;"></div>
        <div id="txtask4" style="text-decoration:underline;color:#8F8F8F;cursor:pointer;"></div>
        <div id="txtask5" style="text-decoration:underline;color:#8F8F8F;cursor:pointer;"></div>
</div
```

### JavaScript

```
$("#fleresvar").click(function () {
    var $element = $(this);
    if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
        $element.removeClass("open");
        $element.children(".txtmore").hide(500);
    } else {
        $(".open").removeClass("open");
        $('.txtmore').hide(500);

        $element.toggleClass('open');
        $element.children('.txtmore').toggle(500);
    }

});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Saph/1/)

Comment: your link is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2Saph/13/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fleresvar").on('click','.handler',function () {
        var $element = $(this).closest('.fleresvar');
        if ($element.hasClass('open')) 
        {
            $element.removeClass("open");
            $element.find(".txtmore").hide(500);
        } 
        else 
        {
            $(".open").removeClass("open");
            $('.txtmore').hide(500);    
            $element.addClass('open');
            $element.find('.txtmore').show(500);
        }    
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="fleresvar" class="fleresvar">  
    <div class="handler"><u><b>Klik her for at se flere svar</b></u></div>
    <div id="txtmore" class="txtmore" style="display:none;">
        <div id="txtask1" style="text-decoration:underline;color:#8F8F8F;cursor:pointer;">txtask1</div>
        <div id="txtask2" style="text-decoration:underline;color:#8F8F8F;cursor:pointer;">txtask2</div>
        <div id="txtask3" style="text-decoration:underline;color:#8F8F8F;cursor:pointer;">txtask3</div>
        <div id="txtask4" style="text-decoration:underline;color:#8F8F8F;cursor:pointer;">txtask4</div>
        <div id="txtask5" style="text-decoration:underline;color:#8F8F8F;cursor:pointer;">txtask5</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="fleresvar2" class="fleresvar"> 
    <div class="handler"><u><b>Klik her for at se flere svar</b></u></div>
    <div id="txtmore" class="txtmore" style="display:none;">
        <div id="txtask1" style="text-decoration:underline;color:#8F8F8F;cursor:pointer;">txtask1</div>
        <div id="txtask2" style="text-decoration:underline;color:#8F8F8F;cursor:pointer;">txtask2</div>
        <div id="txtask3" style="text-decoration:underline;color:#8F8F8F;cursor:pointer;">txtask3</div>
        <div id="txtask4" style="text-decoration:underline;color:#8F8F8F;cursor:pointer;">txtask4</div>
        <div id="txtask5" style="text-decoration:underline;color:#8F8F8F;cursor:pointer;">txtask5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works fine, but when i try using it. It closes again after it has been open. it was the last link i tried.

Comment: Well this is the point of toggle - every click it changes its state from hidden to visible and from visible to hidden.

Comment: IF you want accordion kind of functionality check the last fiddle

Comment: Yes i know. But i only click once.

Comment: When you click on txtask divs do you want them to collapse?

Comment: No. When you click #fleresvar, i want it to show txtmore, and if you click it again, it shall hide

Answer (score 0):

show/hide script

```
    var toggle = 0;

$("#fleresvar").click(function (e) {
if (toggle == 0) {
            $('.txtmore').stop(true,true).show('500');
            toggle = 1;
        } else if (toggle == 1) {
            $('.txtmore').stop(true,true).hide('500');
            toggle = 0;
        }
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;

});
```

and example

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2Saph/10/)

Answer (score 0):

[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Saph/11/):

```
$("#fleresvar").click(function () {
    var $element = $(this);
    if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
        $element.removeClass("open");
        $element.children(".txtmore").hide(500);
    } else {
        $(".open").removeClass("open");        

        $element.toggleClass('open');
        $element.children('.txtmore').show(500);
        $('.txtmore').show(500);
    }

});
```

Comment: Works fine, but when i try using it. It closes again after it has been open

Comment: updated answer: last line should be             `$('.txtmore').show(500);` instead of hide()

Comment: Just tried it, and it's still closing when using it. Can there be something wrong with the css or something else ? #fleresvar is display:none at first, when typing in a text field, it changes to: $("#fleresvar").css("display", "block"); Can this have any effect ?

Comment: Still open and closes right after. Tried to change the CSS so see the BG change, but it's never turning red.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code does work, but there is no content inside of the txtask* divs, so there is nothing being displayed. If you add something in them, you will see the toggle in action. However, I have a few suggestions:

The `<u>` and `<b>` tags were deprecated in HTML4, then brought back in HTML5 for use with semantic meaning. In other words, these tags should only be used if they add meaning (for example, if your underlining a word that is misspelt). You should use the CSS `text-decoration: underline;` and `font-weight: bold;` to achieve the same effect. See here for more info: http://html5doctor.com/u-element/

This line: `$element.children(".txtmore").hide(500);` can be simplified to: `$('#txtmore').hide(500);`

This does two things: You don't have to use the children function anymore, so there is less processing. Also, selecting by ID in jQuery is *much* faster than selecting by class. It won't make a difference for 5 elements, but it will when you get into more complex projects. If the element you need is unique (i.e. there is only one on the whole page) then use an ID.

It looks like you want to toggle the .open class on the main #fleresvar div; if this is the only place, then these two lines are conflicting:
`$(".open").removeClass("open");`
`$element.toggleClass('open');`

The first line will remove .open from all elements with .open, then the second will add .open to #fleresvar.
If you only want to add/remove it from the main element, then either do `$element.addClass('open')` and `$element.removeClass('open')`, OR `$element.toggleClass('open')` twice. I personally like to use addClass and removeClass, so that I know for sure that the class was added/removed.

For the txtask* divs: instead of putting the same inline styles on each one, add a common class to them, then move the styles to your CSS file.

Here is the jsFiddle with my recommended changes: http://jsfiddle.net/2Saph/9/

HTML:

```
<div id="fleresvar" class="fleresvar">Klik her for at se flere svar
    <div id="txtmore" class="txtmore">
        <div id="txtask1" class='txtask'>a</div>
        <div id="txtask2" class='txtask'>b</div>
        <div id="txtask3" class='txtask'>c</div>
        <div id="txtask4" class='txtask'>d</div>
        <div id="txtask5" class='txtask'>e</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#fleresvar").on('click', function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    var $element = $(this);
    if ($element.hasClass('open')) {
        $element.removeClass("open");
        $('#txtmore').hide(500);
    } else {
        $element.addClass("open");
        $('#txtmore').show(500);
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
#fleresvar {
    cursor:pointer;
    background-position: 0 4px;
    min-height: 15px;
    border: 0 solid #000000;
    margin: 2px 0 5px 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 15px;
    background-image:url('/images/images/Pil_normal.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#fleresvar.open {
    background-image: url('/images/images/Pil_open.png');
}
#txtmore {
    display: none;
    width: 280px;
    min-height:15px;
    border: 0 solid #000000;
    margin: 0;
}
div.txtask {
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:#8F8F8F;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: the txtask are getting content from JSON